# ElasticSearch: is there a limit to the size of "terms" when doing a match on multiple values?

Tags: elasticsearch

My use case: I am using a graph database to determine access/visibility to documents in my ElasticSearch index.  I would like to be able to execute a compound search query with a clause that will use an array of "visible" documents ("terms"), where each entry in "terms" will match an id for a document in the index.

Is there any sort of upper-bound to the size of this array?  I am expecting that a typical query may have 1000s of "terms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get 1000 matching documents, there are two way to do it. The first method is the one you mentioned - using the size parameter. This will create problems as your size number keeps increasing. Its advisable to use the [helpers.scan](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan) method and iterate over the cursor returned.

Comment: My main objective is to be able to search within a "collection" of documents, where the collection is identified by "terms", it sounds like this will be OK, as long as the number of terms is in the order of thousands, right?

Comment: Would help me understand the problem better if you can post your query and the exact use-case.

Comment: I am still in the design phase, have not yet implemented it, but this has been helpful.  Thanks.